# Aplicativo roda pelo visual studio, mas não roda quando executado

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

Estou usando o visual studio 2017, criei um aplicativo com WPF, o aplicativo roda normalmente dentro do visual studio em debug mode, porém se eu compila-lo e rodar de dentro da pasta release, ele nem inicia.

Também não inicia se tentar rodar a partir da pasta debug.
As dependencias aparentemente estão corretas.

Consultando o log de erro do windows. tive o seguinte resultado. (Log completo)

```
.NET Runtime
=======================================================================
Aplicativo: ColetaDigital.exe
Versão do Framework: v4.0.30319
Descrição: O processo foi terminado devido a uma exceção sem tratamento.
Informações da Exceção: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   em ColetaDigital.View.PessoaWindow..ctor()
   em ColetaDigital.App..ctor()
   em ColetaDigital.App.Main()
=======================================================================

Application Error
=======================================================================
Nome do aplicativo com falha: ColetaDigital.exe, versão: 1.0.0.0, carimbo de data/hora: 0x5a870628
Nome do módulo com falha: KERNELBASE.dll, versão: 6.3.9600.17415, carimbo de data/hora: 0x54505737
Código de exceção: 0xe0434352
Deslocamento da falha: 0x0000000000008b9c
ID do processo com falha: 0x20e4
Hora de início do aplicativo com falha: 0x01d3a7442ad30549
Caminho do aplicativo com falha: C:\WorkspaceHumberto\Uzer\Projects\ColetaDigital\ColetaDigital\bin\x64\Release\ColetaDigital.exe
Caminho do módulo com falha: C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
ID do Relatório: 689c2aa2-1337-11e8-82d0-641c67786bc9
Nome completo do pacote com falha: 
ID do aplicativo relativo ao pacote com falha: 
=======================================================================

Window Error Reporting
=======================================================================
Falha no bucket 1884401921137980673, tipo 5
Nome do Evento: CLR20r3
Resposta: Não disponível
ID do CAB: 0

Assinatura do problema:
P1: ColetaDigital.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 5a870628
P4: ColetaDigital
P5: 1.0.0.0
P6: 5a870628
P7: 3
P8: 17
P9: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
P10: 

Arquivos anexados:
C:\Users\Pós Venda 02\AppData\Local\Temp\WER15A9.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
C:\Users\Pós Venda 02\AppData\Local\Temp\WER1CFD.tmp.appcompat.txt
C:\Users\Pós Venda 02\AppData\Local\Temp\WER1D0D.tmp.dmp
C:\Users\Pós Venda 02\AppData\Local\Temp\WER1D5D.tmp.WERDataCollectionFailure.txt

Esses arquivos podem estar disponíveis em:
C:\Users\Pós Venda 02\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_ColetaDigital.ex_4e653f8ba129975abac06dcb31b7db17f30cfa2_19a790df_27981d5a

Símbolo da análise: 
Verificando novamente solução: 0
ID do Relatório: 689c2aa2-1337-11e8-82d0-641c67786bc9
Status do Relatório: 4104
Bucket com hash: bff7b2f985abec0a5a26bd90337e3501
=======================================================================
```

Editado:

Código onde o windows aponta erro (classe ColetaDigital.View.PessoaWindow):

```
using ColetaDigital.ViewModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Sagem.MorphoKit;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using Models;
using DataAccess;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ColetaDigital.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for PessoaWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PessoaWindow : Window, IDisposable
    {
        private AcquisitionDevice mDevice;
        private System.Windows.Controls.TextBox mDeviceStatus;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox mDeviceDisplay;
        private System.Windows.Controls.ProgressBar mDeviceQuality;

        private PessoaPermanente mPessoaSelecionada;
        private DataContext mDataContext;

        private Thread mDeviceConnectMonitor;
        private bool mDeviceConnectionStatus;

        private App mApp;

        #region events
        public event EventHandler DeviceConnected;
        #endregion

        public PessoaWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            mApp = Application.Current as App;
            mDevice = new AcquisitionDevice();

            mDevice.FingerEvent += new FingerEventHandler(device_FingerEvent);
            mDevice.EnrolmentEvent += new EnrolmentEventHandler(device_EnrolmentEvent);
            mDevice.QualityEvent += new QualityEventHandler(_device_QualityEvent);
            mDevice.ImageEvent += new ImageEventHandler(device_ImageEvent);

            DeviceConnected += PessoaWindow_DeviceConnected;
            MonitorarLeitor();
        }

        private void MonitorarLeitor()
        {
            mDeviceConnectMonitor = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    IAcquisitionDeviceInfo[] devices = null;

                    try
                    {
                        devices = mDevice.EnumerateDevices();
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { }

                    bool DeviceConnectionStatus = devices != null && devices.Count() > 0 && !devices[0].SerialNumber.Equals("");

                    if (DeviceConnectionStatus != mDeviceConnectionStatus)
                    {
                        mDeviceConnectionStatus = DeviceConnectionStatus;
                        DeviceConnected?.Invoke(this, null);
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            });

            mDeviceConnectMonitor.Start();
        }

        delegate void DeviceConnectedHandlerDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);
        private void PessoaWindow_DeviceConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!CheckAccess())
            {
                try
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => PessoaWindow_DeviceConnected(sender, e));
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }

                return;
            }

            lblPlugLeitor.Text = "Leitor " + (mDeviceConnectionStatus ? "conectado" : "desconectado");
        }

        void device_FingerEvent(int status)
        {
            FingerEventStatus feStatus = FingerEventStatus.UNKNOWN;

            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(FingerEventStatus), status))
            {
                feStatus = (FingerEventStatus)status;
            }

            String msg = "";

            switch (feStatus)
            {
                case FingerEventStatus.NO_FINGER_DETECTED:
                    msg = "Dedo não detectado";
                    break;
                case FingerEventStatus.MOVE_FINGER_UP:
                    msg = "Mova para cima";
                    break;
                case FingerEventStatus.MOVE_FINGER_DOWN:
                    msg = "Mova para baixo";
                    break;
                case FingerEventStatus.MOVE_FINGER_LEFT:
                    msg = "Mova para esquerda";
                    break;
                case FingerEventStatus.MOVE_FINGER_RIGHT:
                    msg = "Mova para direita";
                    break;
                case FingerEventStatus.PRESS_FINGER_HARDER:
                    msg = "Pressione mais";
                    break;
                case FingerEventStatus.LATENT:
                    msg = "Latente";
                    break;
                case FingerEventStatus.REMOVE_FINGER:
                    msg = "Remova o dedo";
                    break;
                case FingerEventStatus.OK:
                    msg = "Digital aceita";
                    break;
                case FingerEventStatus.FINGER_DETECTED:
                    msg = "Dedo detectado";
                    break;
                case FingerEventStatus.FINGER_MISPLACED:
                    msg = "Dedo mal posicionado";
                    break;
                case FingerEventStatus.LIVE_OK:
                    msg = "Não remova o dedo";
                    break;
                default:
                    msg = "Sem dedo";
                    break;
            }

            mDeviceStatus.Text = msg;
        }

        void device_EnrolmentEvent(int captureIndex)
        {
            mDeviceStatus.Text = String.Format("Captura {0}", captureIndex);
        }

        void _device_QualityEvent(byte quality)
        {
            mDeviceQuality.Value = quality < mDeviceQuality.Maximum ? quality : mDeviceQuality.Maximum;
        }

        void device_ImageEvent(byte[] buffer, int width, int height, int resolution)
        {

        }

        private Bitmap CreateGreyscaleBitmap(byte[] buffer, int width, int height)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

            BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, bmpData.Scan0, width * height);
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

            ColorPalette pal = bmp.Palette;
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                pal.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
            }

            bmp.Palette = pal;
            return bmp;
        }

        private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            PessoaViewModel o = e.Item as PessoaViewModel;

            if (o != null)
            {
                e.Accepted = o.Codigo.ToUpper().Contains(tbFilter.Text.ToUpper()) || o.Nome.ToUpper().Contains(tbFilter.Text.ToUpper());
            }
        }

        private void tbFilter_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgPessoas.ItemsSource).Refresh();
        }

        private void dgPessoas_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsLoaded)
            {
                tbCodigo.Text = "";
                tbTipo.Text = "";
                tbNome.Text = "";

                picPrincipal.Image = null;
                pbPrincipal.Value = 0;
                tbPrincipal.Text = "";

                picSecundaria.Image = null;
                pbSecundaria.Value = 0;
                tbSecundaria.Text = "";

                picPanico.Image = null;
                pbPanico.Value = 0;
                tbPanico.Text = "";

                mPessoaSelecionada = null;
                mDataContext = null;

                if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    PessoaViewModel o = e.AddedItems[0] as PessoaViewModel;

                    tbCodigo.Text = o.Codigo;
                    tbTipo.Text = o.Tipo;
                    tbNome.Text = o.Nome;

                    mPessoaSelecionada = o.PessoaPermanente;
                    mDataContext = o.DataContext;
                }
            }
        }

        private void btPrincipalCapturar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mDeviceDisplay = picPrincipal;
            mDeviceStatus = tbPrincipal;
            mDeviceQuality = pbPrincipal;

            Bitmap b = CapturarDigital();

            if (b != null)
            {
                Digital digital = new Digital();

                digital.Pessoa = mPessoaSelecionada.Pessoa;
                digital.DedoPanico = "n";
                digital.Template = ExtractTemplateFromBitmap(b);
                digital.DataHora = DateTime.Now;
                digital.Ativa = "s";

                var DigitaisAExcluir = mPessoaSelecionada.Pessoa.Digitais.Where(d => d.DedoPanico == "n");
                mDataContext.Digitais.RemoveRange(DigitaisAExcluir);

                mDataContext.Digitais.Add(digital);
            }
        }

        private static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
        {
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
        }

        private static Image ByteToImage(byte[] bytes)
        {
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            return (Image)converter.ConvertTo(bytes, typeof(Image));
        }

        private void btSecundariaCapturar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mDeviceDisplay = picSecundaria;
            mDeviceStatus = tbSecundaria;
            mDeviceQuality = pbSecundaria;

            Bitmap b = CapturarDigital();

            if (b != null)
            {
                Digital digital = new Digital();

                digital.Pessoa = mPessoaSelecionada.Pessoa;
                digital.DedoPanico = "n";
                digital.Template = ExtractTemplateFromBitmap(b);
                digital.DataHora = DateTime.Now;
                digital.Ativa = "s";

                // Comentado aqui para depois verificar a melhor forma de excluir digitais que já estavam cadastradas.
                // Se mantiver esse código, quando cadastrar a digital segundária, seria excluido tudo do banco, inclusive
                // a que foi cadastrada como principal.
                // var DigitaisAExcluir = mPessoaSelecionada.Pessoa.Digitais.Where(d => d.DedoPanico == "n");
                // mDataContext.Digitais.RemoveRange(DigitaisAExcluir);

                mDataContext.Digitais.Add(digital);
            }
        }

        private void btPanicoCapturar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mDeviceDisplay = picPanico;
            mDeviceStatus = tbPanico;
            mDeviceQuality = pbPanico;

            Bitmap b = CapturarDigital();

            if (b != null)
            {
                Digital digital = new Digital();

                digital.Pessoa = mPessoaSelecionada.Pessoa;
                digital.DedoPanico = "s";
                digital.Template = ExtractTemplateFromBitmap(b);
                digital.DataHora = DateTime.Now;
                digital.Ativa = "s";

                var DigitaisAExcluir = mPessoaSelecionada.Pessoa.Digitais.Where(d => d.DedoPanico == "s");
                mDataContext.Digitais.RemoveRange(DigitaisAExcluir);

                mDataContext.Digitais.Add(digital);
            }
        }

        private Bitmap CapturarDigital()
        {
            if (mPessoaSelecionada == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nenhuma pessoa selecionada");
                return null;
            }

            mDevice.Display = mDeviceDisplay.Handle;

            IAcquisitionDeviceInfo[] devices = null;
            try
            {
                devices = mDevice.EnumerateDevices();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }

            try
            {
                foreach (var dev in devices)
                {
                    IAcquisitionResult result = mDevice.Acquire(dev.SerialNumber);
                    AcquisitionError aError = AcquisitionError.UNKNOWN;

                    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(AcquisitionError), result.Status))
                    {
                        aError = (AcquisitionError)result.Status;
                    }

                    String msg = String.Format("Captura de digital {0}", aError.ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show(msg);

                    if (aError == AcquisitionError.OK)
                    {
                        Bitmap b = CreateGreyscaleBitmap(result.ImageBuffer as byte[], result.Width, result.Height);
                        mDeviceDisplay.Image = b;
                        return b;
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            return null;
        }

        private byte[] ExtractTemplateFromBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            Coder coder = new Coder();
            coder.TemplateFormat = TemplateFormat.ANSI_378;
            ICoderResult coderResult = coder.EnrollBitmap(bmp, 2);

            return coderResult.Template as byte[];
        }

        private void btSalvar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mDataContext != null)
            {
                mDataContext.SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Dados salvos com sucesso!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nenhuma pessoa selecionada");
            }
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            mDeviceConnectMonitor.Abort();
            mApp.Shutdown();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tbUsuarioLogado.Text = mApp.UsuarioLogado;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            mDevice.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="ColetaDigital.View.PessoaWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
    mc:Ignorable="d"

    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ColetaDigital.ViewModel"

    Title="Bioacesso - Captura de Digitais"

    Height="716"
    Width="1242"

    MinHeight="600"
    MinWidth="842"

    Closing="Window_Closing"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    >

    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:PessoasViewModel x:Key="PessoasViewModel"/>

        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Key="cvsPessoas"
            Source="{StaticResource PessoasViewModel}"
            Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter"
            />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Header="Pesquisa" Margin="20,20,740,100">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox
                    Margin="10,10,10,0"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    x:Name="tbFilter"

                    KeyUp="tbFilter_KeyUp"
                    />

                <DataGrid
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                    CanUserAddRows="False"
                    IsReadOnly="true"
                    Margin="10,53,10,10"

                    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#cac0c0"
                    VerticalGridLinesBrush="#cac0c0"

                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsPessoas}}"
                    x:Name="dgPessoas"

                    SelectionChanged="dgPessoas_SelectionChanged"
                    >

                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Codigo" Binding="{Binding Codigo}" Width="60"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nome" Binding="{Binding Nome}" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tipo" Binding="{Binding Tipo}" Width="150"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">

                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6 3" />

                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                            <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>

                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Dados da Pessoa" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,20,0" Width="712" Height="193">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="/ColetaDigital;component/Assets/Images/no-image.png" Width="150" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="Fill" Margin="10,10,0,0" x:Name="imgFoto"/>

                <!-- Código -->
                <TextBlock Foreground="#ed6c44" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="CÓDIGO" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,27,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" x:Name="tbCodigo"/>
                <!-- Código -->

                <!-- Tipo -->
                <TextBlock Foreground="#ed6c44" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TIPO" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,27,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" x:Name="tbTipo"/>
                <!-- Tipo -->

                <!-- Nome -->
                <TextBlock Foreground="#ed6c44" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,60,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="NOME" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,77,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" x:Name="tbNome"/>
                <!-- Nome -->
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Captura da Digital Principal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,213,501,100" Width="231">
            <Grid>
                <WindowsFormsHost Visibility="Visible" Margin="11,11,11,112">
                    <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
                        <wf:PictureBox x:Name="picPrincipal"/>
                    </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
                </WindowsFormsHost>

                <Border BorderBrush="#c7c7c7" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10,10,10,111"/>

                <ProgressBar Margin="10,0,10,96" Maximum="120" x:Name="pbPrincipal" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,53" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="tbPrincipal"/>

                <Button Content="DESCARTAR" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" Width="97" x:Name="btPrincipalDescartar"/>
                <Button Content="CAPTURAR" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10" Width="97" x:Name="btPrincipalCapturar" Click="btPrincipalCapturar_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Captura da Digital Secundária" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,213,259,100" Width="231">
            <Grid>
                <WindowsFormsHost Visibility="Visible" Margin="11,11,11,112">
                    <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
                        <wf:PictureBox x:Name="picSecundaria"/>
                    </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
                </WindowsFormsHost>

                <Border BorderBrush="#c7c7c7" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10,10,10,111"/>

                <ProgressBar Margin="10,0,10,96" Maximum="120" x:Name="pbSecundaria" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,53" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="tbSecundaria"/>

                <Button Content="DESCARTAR" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" Width="97" x:Name="btSecundariaDescartar"/>
                <Button Content="CAPTURAR" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10" Width="97" x:Name="btSecundariaCapturar" Click="btSecundariaCapturar_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Captura da Digital do Pânico" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,213,20,100" Width="231">
            <Grid>
                <WindowsFormsHost Visibility="Visible" Margin="11,11,11,112">
                    <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
                        <wf:PictureBox x:Name="picPanico"/>
                    </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
                </WindowsFormsHost>
                <Border BorderBrush="#c7c7c7" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10,10,10,111" />

                <ProgressBar Margin="10,0,10,96" Maximum="120" x:Name="pbPanico" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <TextBox Margin="10,0,10,53" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="tbPanico"/>

                <Button Content="DESCARTAR" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" Width="97" x:Name="btPanicoDescartar"/>
                <Button Content="CAPTURAR" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10" Width="97" x:Name="btPanicoCapturar" Click="btPanicoCapturar_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

        <Button Content="SALVAR" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,21,52" Width="97" x:Name="btSalvar" Click="btSalvar_Click"/>

        <StatusBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="9,5">
            <StatusBarItem>
                <TextBlock Text="Leitor desconectado" x:Name="lblPlugLeitor" />
            </StatusBarItem>

            <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <TextBlock Text="" x:Name="tbUsuarioLogado" />
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: O que acontece é que sua aplicação esta tentando acessar um arquivo que não existe, e você não trata isso fazendo ele chamar um FailFast(). Você faz a leitura de um arquivo utilizando o caminho absoluto?

Comment: O estranho é que não faço leitura de nenhum arquivo. Poderia ser as dependências? Elas estão sendo adicionadas normalmente dentro da pasta release ou debug. Outro detalhe é que essa classe: ColetaDigital.View.PessoaWindow é relativa a um xaml. será que erros no xaml podem causar isso, de funcionar dentro do visual studio e não fora?

Comment: É bem provável que isso seja problema com referências. Compartilhe seu código para a gente analisar.

Comment: Eu postei a classe com seu respectivo XAML. não sei se o erro está nessa. O Log do windows diz que sim. O código já está um pouco extenso então não sei como postar ele completo

Comment: Ao tentar rodar a aplicação de dentro do Visual Studio, como release em vez de debug, me é apresentada uma mensagem "Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)". Estou pressentindo que isso pode me ajudar a resolver a questão, mas o vs não mostra mais detalhes do erro. Você sabe como identificar erros que ocorrem dessa forma? Aparentemente é no XAML.

Comment: Me parece um erro inesperado ele abrir o break state. Tentou continuar executando para ver se rola uma exceção?

Comment: não gera exceção, apenas para a execução.

Comment: Se eu excluo a tela PessoaWindow, a aplicação roda. é alguma coisa nessa tela mesmo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73269/discussion-between-gabriel-coletta-and-jairhumberto).

Comment: provavelmente ele entra em break state pq vc nao implementou por 3 vezes o catch (Exception) { }. Pode verificar isso? provavelmente é este o motivo de seu app quebrar. Se for eu transformo esse comentario em resposta.

Comment: não entendi, você quis dizer, implementar um try sem catch por 3 vezes? ou deixar de tratar qualquer tipo de exceção por 3 vezes?